# Ordering activerecord relationship from a specific starting value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I get a `photo_id` 34

This photo is part of a specific photographers asset `current_photographer.photos.all` : 1, 23, 24, 34, 78

How is it possible to get the relationship `current_photographer.photos.all` result starting by the specific photo ID provided => 34, 78, 1, 23, 24 ?

EDIT: I want to keep the general order of photos. Each photo is preceeded by the previously created photo.(this is for a photo carousel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create two result sets, one for >= 34 and one for < 34, and then combine them.

`current_photographer.photos.where('id >= ?', 34) + current_photographer.photos.where('id < ?', 34)`

These could be scopes:

```
scope :above_id, ->(id) { where('id >= ?', id) }
scope :below_id, ->(id) { where('id < ?', id) }
```

then: `current_photographer.photos.above_id(34) + current_photographer.photos.below_id(34)`

or add a class method using the scopes:

```
def self.above_below_id(id)
  above_id(id) + below_id(id)
end
```

Comment: I was focused on finding the solution with a single query.. But your solution definitely does the job. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you would be better implementing in the application space. I don't really see how it can be done in a meaningful way in the database level.

You can fetch the records in their original order and then manipulate the result.

```
current_photographer.photos.partition {|photo| photo.id < 34 }.reverse.flatten
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution does work in a single query. I have already accepted the other answer but yours is slightly cleaner. Manipulating a single query is the way to go.